# Xcode imports RestKit.h correctly in two files, but not into another file in the same bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, restkit, xcode4.5

I am having trouble making sense of what is going on here. I have a project using the Restkit Framework Library. The project was setup using Pods to install the framework and generate a workspace file.

I have three classes that are using RestKit.h, two of them (my app delegate, and my ViewController) import  correctly, while a new file (a new ViewController) gives a red error on the import statement saying `RestKit/RestKit.h file not found`. Then when I try to use RestKit, I do not get code completion from xcode. However, the project builds and runs correctly after inserting RestKit Code.

Furthermore if I click "Jump To Definition" on the drop down menu when right-clicking a RestKit method in xcode, it takes me to RestKit source, implying that Xcode actually does know about the RestKit library.

Xcode version is 4.5.2

Any advice on where to look would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Same target? Are you working in the .xcworkspace?

Comment: They are in the same target, strangely, It seems that the problem was that the source in question was being compiled for both my project, and my projects tests. When I removed the source from the Compile Sources part of the build phase for the Tests target, the problem was fixed...

Comment: can you explain how to fixed it ?